# Socket server in Windows service Runs on windows 10 but not on windows server

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, windows-server

I have a Socket server that in a service that connects on my PC(windows 10) but not on the server(windows server)

The socket, which listens for requests, works on my pc as a service as well as in a console, on the server it works as a console but not as a service

I checked the firewall, and even tried running in when the firewall is down

```cs
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));

            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<TCPListenerService>();
                });

            if (isService)
            {
                await builder.RunAsServiceAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
            }
        }
```

No error messages what so ever, when i try connecting to socket i get times out on the client side

Comment: These are probably user permission issues. What user is used to run the service on the server?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen admin

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past, you'll need to go into windows firewall settings and add your application as an exception with public and or private networks enabled depending on what you're using, otherwise it will appear to "run" fine but not be able to process any connections.

It might be worthwhile also running the application as administrator in case the default user role doesn't allow for outbound connections.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work even with the firewall disabled.

Comment: _"worthwhile also running the application as administrator"_ - Please, don't.